# which is best view or surfaceview for image upload on server android

Tags: android, camera

i want to capture the image from camera and upload on server

for capturing image which is best direct  using intent simple sort code or using view or surfaceview which is best

Answer (score 1):

when you use the basic `Intent`, you don't really need to bother with sufaceView or View. the user is prompt with the image and is asked if to save it or not. using the `onActivityResult` will take care of the upload.

have you looked at the [android camera image capture](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)? they have sample code for all the possibilities of capturing images from the android camera.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some customization in your activity or some other functionality with image capturing then surfaceview is best. One example i have already given you can try this to capture frames. I have explained everything if you are having any problem then you can ask I will try to help you. Instead of onPreviewFrame use on picture taken.

[Android Camera Surface View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482057/android-camera-surface-view/10482872#10482872)

hope it will help you.

Comment: i want capture the image from camera and display in imageview after give the effect on image

Comment: you can see this link for example if i user surface view is create any problem for this <http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=instagram&hl=en&client=firefox-a&sa=X&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1467&bih=707&tbm=isch&prmd=imvnsa&tbnid=psDhBp5XTsuWWM:&imgrefurl=https://foursquare.com/app/instagram&docid=PXxXqey-4PRnnM&imgurl=https://playfoursquare.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/1K1CBOXE5LZEEYS4.png&w=320&h=480&ei=9p-wT4riCsyJrAfalcXwAw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=179&vpy=266&dur=6111&hovh=275&hovw=183&tx=98&ty=123&sig=107909598838583184261&page=1&tbnh=143&tbnw=100&start=0&ndsp=22&ved=1t:429,r:15,s:0,i:108

Comment: Whatever you have shown me if that is preview not an image which you have captured then you need surface view to show buttons and all other things. But if you want to display your captured image only not preview then you can take picture by using default camera application and then set your captured image in your own activity. So it depends on your case.