# camerasurfaceview is black in screenshot

Tags: android, screenshot

I want to publish my augmented reality application but the problem is that when i try to take screen-shot of my application the live image of the camera is black in the screen-shot whereas in my device everything works good. how can i solve this?

Comment: refer this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482057/android-camera-surface-view

Comment: thanks for your answer but my camerasurfaceview is not the actual problem. everything works fine in my app. the problem is that when i take the screenshot whereas i have a live image in my device the saved image of the screenshot has a black background. the camerasurfaceview works fine. the black screenshot is the problem