# How to save camera instance at run-time while taking video when screen orientation get changed

Tags: android

I am developing an application of video recording. My camera instance get stop whenever I switch my mobile orientation from portrait to landscape and vice-versa. I want to save the camera instance while screen orientation. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not save camera instance instead you should save its index and camera parameter. when you change orientation then your activity will create again. So best way to create video recording gui is to fix orientation to landscape.

Here is the code which you can use to save camera and its settings.

```
//THIS INDEX WHICH YOU ARE PASSING YOU CAN SAVE IN ANY MEMBER VARIABLE.
Camera camera = Camera.open(index);

// BELOW STATEMENT WILL GIVE YOU CAMERA PARAMETER WITH CURRENT SETTINGS.
Camera.Parameters camera_param = camera.getParameters();
```

To save data on orientation change you can use:

```
onSaveInstanceState and get back all parameters in OnCreate or onRestoreInstanceState
```

You better to learn how to restrict orientation while video recording in Android. Why I am forcing you to learn is each device is having different camera orientation in different directions. So if you will restrict your activity and camera in landscape mode then you need not to mess with camera orientation. Here is an example I have already given If you want you can check.

[Android Camera Surface View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482057/android-camera-surface-view/10482872#10482872)

Comment: :I have fix camera orientation to landscape. And now it's working finely. Thank you

Comment: Mark as answer to help other and me. :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow