# draw in the view of the camera in real time

Tags: android

I'm developing an android application for mobile, the application must draw a rectangle while using the camera, the rectangle should only have lines should not be colored, I would like to draw the rectangle on the view of the camera in real time, I have fragments code but am getting more lost. My android version is 4.3.
Could someone let me an example of code to do what I ask?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a surfaceView that shows the camera's image. You can draw on that view as well, which enables you to show the rectangle. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10482872/2910492) for an example.

Comment: I would like to do something like this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/images/camera-area-coordinates.png

Comment: Where did you find that image? That page in the documentation probably also shows you how to implement it.

Comment: on page is a snippet of code, I've added to mine but I locked the camera makes my application stop working, just need to show a box on my camera, then the image within that box will do more stuff

Comment: some of the errors that I get the program to compile:

Comment: 12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.exercise.camaraf/com.exercise.camaraf.AndroidCamera}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.exercise.camaraf.AndroidCamera" on path: /data/app/com.exercise.camaraf-1.apk
12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2381)

Comment: 12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

Comment: 12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)

Comment: 12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.exercise.camaraf.AndroidCamera" on path: /data/app/com.exercise.camaraf-1.apk
12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

Comment: 12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
12-06 23:04:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(14562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)

Comment: could send my code for you to prove, thanks