# Google Glass - Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) doesn't show view finder but immediately takes a snapshot

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

On Google Glass, calling Camera via Intent as below immediately takes a picture instead of showing camera view finder.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST);
```

Does anyone know a way to show a view finder (and "Tap to Scan" text overlaying) exactly as Google Glass Settings app does when letting you scan the QRCode on (https://glass.google.com/myglass) to connect to Wifi?

Comment: I think your best bet is to try and use Zxing: https://github.com/zxing/zxing which is trivial to run on Android, but may take some tweaks on Glass.  A google search will get you others experience getting it to work on Glass.  I assume your main goal is to scan a QR code.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have a SurfaceView that shows the camera preview, instead of letting the camera app do the work.

See [Android Camera Surface View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482057/android-camera-surface-view) for how to do this in Android (code will also work on Glass).