# Blur Camera View on Google Glass

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-glass, augmented-reality, vuforia

I looked around all internet and still has no solution to my issue.

I am trying to launch a very simple AR app on Google Glass. Project is created in Unity 3D with Vuforia plugin. I already got app on the GGlass, so it start with voice trigger "Play a game" and then I can see the the "powered by unity" intro.

But, my camera on Glass after this is just blur. Not even a clear camera view, and of course no reaction on AR or markers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.unity3d.player"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger" android:resource="@xml/my_voice_trigger" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is what I have in my project Plugins/AndroidManifest http://slides.com/annadubovik/deck--3 
Sorry for way too much code, but this is first time I am working with all this (Android, Unity and Glass)

Can someone give me a hint where to look and what to do?

Comment: Post code, post more details, help us, help you!

Comment: @FunctionR Please, find the listing [here](http://slides.com/annadubovik/deck--3)

Comment: Can you post the code for the camera?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your use case, but the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482057/android-camera-surface-view) may help you. In particular, take notice of the `Camera` calls in `surfaceCreated()` and `surfaceChanged()`.

The camera preview was not blurry when I tried it.